# Condition for moving elements

Tags: magento2, product, template-override

I have a problem with this one so I'm editing the **catalog_product_view.xml** and I'm trying to move product details before add to cart button. So I have a configurable product and a simple product and I have these two lines that conflicts with each other.

```
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.form.options" before="product.info.options.wrapper" />
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.form.content" before="product.info.addtocart" />
```

How can I make  a condition for this? The first line is for configurable products while the second one is for simple product. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For configurable products you can use separate layout file i.e `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

You can check default file at:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: instead of using `catalog_product_view.xml `, use 2 separate layout files `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` and `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`